# Running Windows XP rs232 software on Windows 10 PC

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, rs232, com-port

I have a piece of software that communicates with CNC machines  using a usb to rs232 converter. The software communicates perfectly on Windows XP.

I had to install the same software in compatibility mode on Windows 10 for it to run.

When i use the USB to RS232 converter on the 10 machine,  communications do not work. I don't recieve any feedback or errors.

I also installed an XP virtual machine on the windows 10 machine and installed the communications software. Using the USB to RS232 converter doesn't work on this virtual machine either!

All drivers / software are installed. Everything shows up in device manager exactly as it does in the XP machine. All settings are identical within the com ports.

I have also installed this software and used the Usb to Rs232 converter on other xp machines without any issues ir needing to install any additional drivers etc!

Am I missing something obvious here? Is there an additional chip or hardware component in windows xp machines not available in newer machines. I feel this is an internal hardware issue as the XP virtual machine is identical to the physical xp machine.

This is driving me insane with months now, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The most common issues with USB Serial ports is they register as COM3 or higher, where most older software only recognizes COM1 or COM2. We run into this a lot working on older hospitality and telecommunications equipment and have found the only real answer is a more advanced USB to Serial adapter like the Digi Edgeport USB adapters, which allow you to assigned them a non-conflicting RS-232 COM port and it stays regardless of the USB port it is connected to. I don't know if this is your issue or not, without better testing it's hard to say.

Comment: Cheers for the input- the software works on all COM ports up to 7, it may go higher,  i just never tested